Area of the shaded region $\frac{41}{6} + \frac{2}{3}$ but is $\frac{59}{6}$
Find the area of the shaded region using primitive function.

$$f(x) = x^2 + 5x + 4$$
$X_1 = 1, X_2 = -2$
The limitation I am able to find from the figure,$\left[-2, 1\right]$.
Integral:
$$\int_{-2}^{1} (x^2 + 5x + 4) \, dx$$
$\int_{-2}^{1} (x^2 + 5x + 4) \, dx = \left[\frac{x^3}{3} + \frac{5x^2}{2} + 4x\right]_{-2}^{1}$
Applying:
$F(1)-F(-2) = \frac{41}{6} - (-\frac{2}{3})$
$\frac{41}{6} + \frac{2 \times 2}{3 \times 2} = \frac{41 + 4}{6} = \frac{45}{6}$
My answer was wrong, according to the back of the book the correct solution is: $$\color{red}{\frac{59}{6}}$$.

Re-check your math for the lower bound:
$$\frac{(-2)^3}{3} + \frac{5(-2)^2}{2} + 4(-2) = -\frac{8}{3} + 10 -8 = -\frac{2}{3}$$

Adding to the previous comment, it seems $F(1)$ and $F(-2)$ are wrong, as $F(1) = \frac 13 + \frac 52 + 4 = \frac{41}{6}$ and not $-\frac{41}{6}$, and $F(-2) = \frac{-8}{3}+10-8 = -\frac 23$

@rafilou2003 There was an accidental typo. Thx.

Like this question

Area = $\int_{-2}^{1} \mid x^2 + 5x + 4 \mid \, dx = \int_{-2}^{-1} (-x^2 - 5x - 4)  \, dx + \int_{-1}^{1}  x^2 + 5x + 4  \, dx $
$= \left[\frac{-x^3}{3} - \frac{5x^2}{2} - 4x\right]_{-2}^{-1} + \left[\frac{x^3}{3} + \frac{5x^2}{2} + 4x\right]_{-1}^{1}$
$ = \left[(\frac{-(-1)^3}{3} - \frac{5(-1)^2}{2} - 4(-1)) - (\frac{-(-2)^3}{3} - \frac{5(-2)^2}{2} - 4(-2))\right] + \left[(\frac{1^3}{3} + \frac{5(1)^2}{2} + 4(1) - \frac{(-1)^3}{3} + \frac{5(-1)^2}{2} + 4(-1))\right] = \frac{59}{6} $

Why does the limit change?

I can seeee clearly Now.

If you integrate according to the formula, as you did, then areas under the $x$-axis will count negative. But the question asks for the area of the shaded region; so you have to compute the two regions separately, and add their absolute values.

More generally, if you seek for the area bounded by the curve $y=f(x)$ with $x$-axis and $x=a,x=b$, then it is given by
$$\int^b_a|f(x)|dx$$
with the absolute $|f(x)|$. In your case if you drop the absolute sign, then the region $-1<x<2$ will offset the other part in the integral.
